# Find the index of minimum non negative value in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Assume a numeric vector `x <- c(-3,2,1,-2, 4,-1,-5)` 
 Min non-negative value in `x` is `1` so the index/location/answer should be `3`.
How can we do it by using any function?

(Note: Function `which.min`, in the above case, gives answer/index `7` that is the minimum (but not non negative))

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
which.max(1 / x)
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
which(x==min(x[x>0]))
#[1] 3
```

it tells `R` to search for the `x` that is equal to the minimum of non-negative values.
**Edit**: In case of multiple minima, it will display all of them, so in this case, you can do `min(which(x==min(x[x>0])))`.

***NB***: in this case, you cannot use `which.min` as `which.min(x[x>0])` would give you the index of the minimum value in the vector `x[x>0]` (`2` here)

Answer (score 0):

To find the (first) index of the minimal value of `x` satisfying a more general condition I suggest using a custom function

```
which_min_cond <- function(x, cond) {
    seq_along(x)[cond][which.min(x[cond])]
}
```

where `cond` can be any condition, like `x >= 0` in our case

```
which_min_cond(x, x >= 0)
# [1] 3
```